# jquery-mobile How to change background color of page after a page transition

Tags: jquery-mobile

I want to know how to change the background color after a page transition occurs.

for example when i click the first link and it 'pop' to the next page, the page that it pops to background color changes.

code first page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>first page</h1>
<p>I am the first page!</p>
<a href="page1.html" data-transition="pop">page 1</a>
</body>
</html>
```

code second page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
<style>
  .ui-page { background: #F00;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>second</h1>
    <p>I am the second page!</p>
    <a href="../index.html" data-transition="slidefade">first page</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried many methods on the internet but nothing seems to work including:

```
<style>
  .ui-page { background: #F00;}
</style>
```

This works if i refresh the second page but it doesn't work when i click on the link on the first page for it to transition to second page then change background color...